# How do i display a random image using jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using bootstrap and jQuery. I have 4 pictures and I only want one to show randomly each time someone hits on a button. What I have tried is to make an array of the images and then use the button to call the function but it does not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is the button

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New Photo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is where i want the picture to display

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <img id="picture">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            displayPics();
        });
    });


    function displayPics() {

        var imagesArray = new Array();

        imagesArray = [
            "CM.jpg", "DC.jpg", "MG.jpg", "SW.jpg"
        ]

        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length + 1));
        var img = imagesArray[num];

        $("picture").html("<img src='" + img + "' />")
    }

    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs two fixes.

Fix A: replace this:

`var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length + 1));`

With this:

`var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);`

This is needed because in the original code your random number will range from 0 to 4, instead of the desired 0 to 3.

Fix B: replace this:

`$("picture").html("<img src='" + img + "' />")`

With this:

`$("#picture").attr("src", img);`

This is needed because to select by id you need to add a `#`, and you need to change just the `src` attribute, so using `attr` is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("picture").html("<img src='" + img + "' />");
$("#picture").attr('src',img);
```

you lost html selector.